# Sql Insert Into

Tags: sql, insert

I need to do an insert into but for the fields, they come from 2 seperate tables.

Here is a query which does not seem to work:

```
    insert into @tblfirst (ProgID,ProgDate,Spk,Spkadd)
    values(

    (select ProgID,ProgDate from Prog where ProgSys = '1100),
    (select Spkr,SpkrAdd from Spk where SpkrSys = '201X42')

    )
```

Not sure if you see anything wrong with the statment.

Comment: Are both of these queries guaranteed to return at most one row?

Comment: There is a typo: where ProgSys = '1100'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @ProgID int
declare @ProgDate datetime
declare @Spkr varchar(100)
declare @SpkrAdd varchar(100)

select @ProgID = ProgID, @ProgDate = ProgDate
from Prog
where ProgSys = '1100'

select @Spkr = Spkr, @SpkrAdd = SpkrAdd
from Spk
where SpkrSys = '201X42'  

insert into @tblfirst (ProgID,ProgDate,Spk,Spkadd) 
values (@ProgID, @ProgDate, @Spkr, @SpkrAdd)
```

Disclaimer: I assumed what the datatypes are, but you get the idea.  It's a bit more intuitive and you'll surely have no problems with this `INSERT`.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for this is database-dependent, so the query below is the most portable code I code think of. Note this may cause duplicates. Knwoing the details of your schema may allow a more selective JOIN clause.

Try:

```
insert into @tblfirst (ProgID, ProgDate, Spk, Spkadd)
select p.ProgID, p.ProgDate,
    s.Spk, s.Spkadd
from Prog p
inner join Spk s on 1=1
where p.ProgSys = '1100'
    and s.SpkrSys = '201X42'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
insert into @tblfirst (ProgID,ProgDate,Spk,Spkadd)
values (
    select ProgId,ProgDate, Spkr, SpkrAdd from Prog, Spk 
    where ProgSys = '1100'and 
          SpkrSys = '201X42'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a join?

```
insert into @tblfirst (ProgID,ProgDate,Spk,Spkadd)
select ProgID,ProgDate,Spkr,SpkrAdd 
from Prog, Spk 
where Prog.ProgSys = '1100' and SpkrSys = '201X42'
```

A bit of an odd join I agree but it'll do the job. If there is any relationship between Prog and Spk then this should probably form part of the where clause.